# Disabling sleep on rasberry pi3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

Is there a command line prompt to disable sleep? Or is there a file I can access on the Raspberry Pi to change?

Comment: What do you want to stop sleeping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Force the screen to stay on:

From an SSH session in PuttySSH or a terminal session on the Raspberry Pi itself:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following lines to the [SeatDefaults] section:

```
# don't sleep the screen
xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms
```

CTRL+x to exit, Y to save then enter to accept the filename